# Excel VBA Add a scroller to Form Control Combobox

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering is anyone knows how to add a scroll bar to a form control combobox thats on my excel sheet (not in a user form), because I currently have 40 items in the list and it just goes off screen and I have to use the up and down keys to scroll the list, also is there away to set the length of the list so it a small list with a scroll bar?

I have 1200 of these combobox in my workbook, so I hope there is a generic way to apply this to all combobox's

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click, choose 'Format control', set the 'Drop down lines' number to something like 8. You might want to look into Data Validation lists rather than 1200 controls!

Comment: haha I feel stupid took that as the number of items in the list not the length

Comment: Is there any issue with me using that many controls although data validation will do the same, for aesthetic purposes the control looks better?